# Swapping Array elements with Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to swap two array elements in an array that looks like this

```
[18785:Object, 22260:Object, 22261:Object, 22262:Object, 22263:Object]
```

I used the following code:

```
    that.moveMediumDown = function(mediumID){

        var arrKeys = new Array();

        for (key in that.data.medium) {
            arrKeys.push(parseInt(key));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arrKeys.length; i++){
            if (arrKeys[i] === parseInt(mediumID)) {

                //swap Medium
                var tmpMedium = that.data.medium[arrKeys[i]];
                that.data.medium[arrKeys[i]] = that.data.medium[arrKeys[i + 1]];
                that.data.medium[arrKeys[i + 1]] = tmpMedium;

                break;
            }
        }

        //build new array with correct ids

        var tmpMediumArray = new Array();

        for (var j = 0; j < arrKeys.length; j++){
            tmpMediumArray[arrKeys[j]] = that.data.medium[arrKeys[j]];
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I swap the content of the two array elements, the key stays the same. But I need also to swap the key.

So i tried to build a new array with the correct keys but then I get an Array with 22263 elements. Most of them are undefined and only the 5 are correct.

Is there any method to do this without getting such a big array?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [array_flip](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_flip/) function.

It allows you to swap keys with the elements:

`array_flip( {a: 1, b: 1, c: 2} );`

becomes

`{1: 'b', 2: 'c'}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I try to swap elements and not to flip keys and values. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "swap elements"? You're trying to swap the keys as `arrKeys` with the array elements, so it's the same.

Comment: I try to swap the element at position 1 in the array with the element at position 3 for example. [18785:Object, 22260:Object, 22261:Object, 22262:Object, 22263:Object] -> [ 22261:Object, 22260:Object, 18785:Object, 22262:Object, 22263:Object]

Comment: Why? Are you sorting them? It'd be easier to change their sorting when this array is actually created, but it's possible you don't have access to that.

Comment: So is there no easy way to do this? The problem is more complex than I explained in my question. But I thought there should be an easy solution to swapping two elements.

Comment: There are ways to copy and re-assign values from an array but it's an unusually specific task you're trying to solve. If you're trying to sort, it's best to write a custom `.sort` method.

Comment: Hey thanks. That's probably solving my problem. Didn't know one could write custom .sort functions. I'll give it a try. If I succeed I write an answer to my Question.

Comment: Ah, yes. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects